# gdb attach to a process without stop

Tags: gdb

Everytime I attach to a process using gdb, it will stop the target program, and I need to type 'cont' to let it go.  Is there a way to attach to a process without stopping it?  This makes things easier if the process will behave differently if it stops for a while.

Comment: Why would you attach and continue immediately? My use case has been attach > Set a breakpoint > continue.

Comment: @talekeDskobeDa You attach and continue immediately to catch a crash in the debugger. In this case, there is no need for a breakpoint, and stopping the program can have side effects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't make it not stop. You can however instantly continue... Create a simple batch script which will attach to a specific process and instantly continuing execution after attaching:

```
gdb attach $1 -x <(echo "cont")
```

> ./attach PID

Answer (score 48):

I know there is already a fine answer for this, but I prefer not using an additional file.

Here is another answer:

```
gdb attach $(pidof process_name) -ex cont
```

Comment: I had to disable pagination, because on attach there were too many threads, and gdb did not perform 'continue' before user intervention: `gdb -iex "set pagination off" -q -ex cont -p $PID`

Answer (score 3):

For when you don't know the PID of the process...

```
gdb attach $(pgrep -f myApp) -ex cont
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a unified command for recent versions of GDB that include [`debuginfod` support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143650/1004497) (also see a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143650/1004497)). Without this additional step, it was still hanging my remote terminal, which was hard to detect while I was attempting to debug a window-manager issue. In this example, `<BINARY-NAME>` is the process binary name, in case you don't know/don't want to find the PID.

```
echo 'set debuginfod enabled on' >> ~/.gdbinit
gdb -iex "set pagination off" -q -ex cont -p $(pidof <BINARY-NAME>)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).