# GDB keeps downloading debug info

Tags: c++, gdb

Every now and then, when I launch a debug process, GDB starts by downloading all debug info for all dependencies, which is not negligeable. Given the fact that dependencies don't get added THAT often, I suspect it's because I am using rolling distro, so every time I perform a distribution upgrade, GDB will re-downloads debug info upon next launch (might be completely wrong on that one, I don't know)

After looking into documentation, I tried:

```
...
Downloading separate debug info for /lib64/libFLAC.so.8...
Downloading separate debug info for /lib64/libspeex.so.1...
Downloading separate debug info for /lib64/libopus.so.0...
...
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
...

# Huh?
denis@localhost:~> file /usr/lib/debug
/usr/lib/debug: cannot open `/usr/lib/debug' (No such file or directory)

denis@localhost:/usr> sudo find . -name debug
./share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/contrib/debug
./include/c++/10/debug
./include/c++/11/debug
./src/linux-5.13.13-1/arch/arm/include/debug
./src/linux-5.13.13-1/kernel/debug
./src/linux-5.13.13-1/tools/power/cpupower/debug
./src/linux-5.14.0-3.g501d1f1/arch/arm/include/debug
./src/linux-5.14.0-3.g501d1f1/kernel/debug
./src/linux-5.14.0-3.g501d1f1/tools/power/cpupower/debug
./lib64/node_modules/npm16/node_modules/debug
denis@localhost:/usr>
```

How do I download and store, and adjust GDB to use the same debug info?

If that's of any importance, I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed

Comment: I have not seen a version of GDB which _itself_ downloads anything. I _have_ seen versions which tell you the command to do so. What rolling distribution are you using?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Tumbleweed, as I specified above

Comment: Is the environment variable `DEBUGINFOD_URLS` set?

Comment: GDB has support for debuginfod server since version 10, so it can download debuginfo itself if it was configured to do it.

Comment: @ssbssa yes, it is set to https://debuginfod.opensuse.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GDB uses `debuginfod_find_debuginfo()` to find and download the debug info files. [Documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libdebuginfod-dev/debuginfod_find_source.3.en.html) says:

```
debuginfod_find_debuginfo(), debuginfod_find_executable(), and debuginfod_find_source()
query the debuginfod server URLs contained in $DEBUGINFOD_URLS
(see below) for the debuginfo ...
...

CACHE
If the query is successful, the debuginfod_find_*() functions save the target
file to a local cache. The location of the cache is controlled by the
$DEBUGINFOD_CACHE_PATH environment variable (see below).
Cleaning of the cache is controlled by the cache_clean_interval_s and
max_unused_age_s files, which are found in the $DEBUGINFOD_CACHE_PATH directory.
cache_clean_interval_s controls how frequently the cache is traversed for cleaning
and max_unused_age_s controls how long a file can go unused
(fstat(2) atime) before it's removed from the cache during cleaning.
```

So it seems like you are suffering from either too frequent cleaning, or too low `max_unused_age_s` setting.

And unsetting `DEBUGINFOD_URLS` in the environment should stop GDB from downloading anything.

Comment: thanks, I found the max_unused_age_s file in `~/.cache/debuginfod_client`, and modified it for a greater value, it was only 1 week

Answer (score 3):

This issue was fixed inside gdb, see https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27532. In particular from https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27532#c5 :

> Hi Sergio. Since commit 7811fa5995 gdb will print a notice when
> debuginfod is enabled and give the user a chance to opt out. Closing
> this bug as FIXED.

Starting from [7811fa5995](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=7811fa5995) version gdb has a new command `set debuginfod`. You can completely disable debuginfod with the following command in future release of gdb:

```
set debuginfod enabled off
```

Comment: The command is:
set debuginfod enabled off

Answer (score 0):

To opt out for your current login, do this from bash:

`$ unset DEBUGINFOD_URLS`

Put that command in your `~/.bashrc` file if you want the change to persist between logins.

Comment: Or create a `~/.gdbinit` file with the line `set debuginfod enabled off`.